# JAVA PrintWriter println method

Tags: java, printwriter, println

I am trying to use the `println` method of `PrintWriter` to write the following to a single line:

```
100,iPod,Book,100
```

The types of the above are: `Int, String, String, double,`respectively.

Can someone please tell me how this can be accomplished? Thanks.

Comment: Use `+` to concatenate strings.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote stranger :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you mean:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
int i1= 100;
String str2="ipod";
String str3="book";
double d4=100;
pw.println(i1+","+str2+","+str3+","+d4);
```

Answer (score 0):

For every object you write that isnt string, you use String.valueOf(a);

So it would be

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(100) + " " + "iPod" + "Book" + String.valueOf(100));
```

or

```
System.out.println("100" + " " + "iPod" + "Book" + "100");
```

Comment: Or not. The string concatenation operator does that anyway.